# How often can you use a Scroll of Protection?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

How often can you use a Scroll of Protection?

In the DMG, p.200, I can see that Spell Scrolls are one-use items

But in the DMG, p.199, I can't see any reference to the Scroll of Protection being used up on activating it. So it sort of looks like it can be used many time, which might tie in with the fact that it's a Rare item?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're missing the general rules for scrolls, on page 139 of the DMG.

> A scroll is a consumable magic item. Whatever the nature of the magic contained in a scroll, unleashing that magic requires using an action to read the scroll. **When its magic has been invoked, the scroll can't be used again.** Its words fade, or it crumbles into dust.